# Get null value from another object in Java, but get value in own class

Tags: java, oop, object

When I try to execute this code, after I choose AMD, I got null in value. how it can be happen ?
below is the source code :
[for main]

```
public class processor{
    public int hargapro;
    public String nmbarangpro;
    public static final Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public String getpro()
    {
        return nmbarangpro;
    }
    public int getproharga()
    {
        return hargapro;
    }
    public void daftarpro() {
        List<String> daftarpro = new ArrayList<>();
        daftarpro.add("AMD");
        daftarpro.add("Intel");
        List<String> nomer = new ArrayList<>();
        nomer.add("1. ");
        nomer.add("2. ");
        System.out.println("Processor yang tersedia :");
        for (int i = 0; i < daftarpro.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(nomer.get(i)+daftarpro.get(i));
            } 
        System.out.println("Pilihan anda : ");
        int pilih = input.nextInt();
        switch(pilih)
        {
            case 1:
            {
            System.out.println("Anda membeli Processor AMD");
            System.out.println("Seharga Rp 1.200.000");
            harga(1200000); //call harga method
            namabarang("AMD"); //call namabarang method
            System.out.println(getpro()); //[for testing]filled with AMD[ni problem here]
            System.out.println(getproharga()); //[for testing][filled with 1200000[no problem here]
            break;
            }
            case  2:
            {
            System.out.println("Anda membeli Processor AMD");
            System.out.println("Seharga Rp 1.200.000");
            harga(1500000);
            namabarang("Intel");  
            break;
            }
            default:
            System.out.println("Pilihan tidak tersedia");
            daftarpro();
        }

        }
    @Override
    public int harga(int hargamasuk) {
        return hargapro = hargamasuk;


    }

    @Override
    public String namabarang(String barang) {
        return nmbarangpro = barang; 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        processor a = new processor();
        a.daftarpro();//get menu from daftarpro()
        kasir x = new kasir();
        x.semua();//get null in value 
    }
        }
```

my second files :

```
public class kasir {
public void semua()
{
    processor a = new processor();
    System.out.println(a.getpro());
}}
```

When I try to read value through class kasir, i get x.semua filled with null value. how it can be happen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `semua` method creates a new instance of `processor` which it then reads from:

```
public void semua()
{
    processor a = new processor();
    System.out.println(a.getpro());
}
```

That's entirely unrelated to the `processor` instance you've created in your `main` method. If your `kasir` class should logically "know about" the other `processor` instance, you probably want a `processor` field in the class, which you might populate via the constructor - so your `main` method might become:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    processor a = new processor();
    a.daftarpro();
    kasir x = new kasir(a);
    x.semua();
}
```

As an aside, you should really try to follow the Java naming conventions, so classes of `Processor` and `Kasir`, and methods of `getPro` etc. (And if your code actually looks like that in your editor, I suggest you reformat it, too...)

Comment: Sorry for my english before,
thank you very much for your help. this question resolved. i will try to learn java naming conventions.